# getting thread names in stop() method

Tags: java, multithreading

how can I get in stop() thread names like i did in start()? Thread names are A,B,C,D. My program runs thread in order and stops them in revers order. But I have problem with printing their names. In start() I do it without any problems but in stop() I just dont know how to do it. I'm pretty new in java and this is one of my firs programs that I did that is why i dont know how to do this. 
Thank you so much for your help. 
Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.*;

class Service extends Thread
{
  private RobotController controller;
  public String robotID;
  private byte[] lock;                                          

  public Service(RobotController cntrl, String id)
  {
    controller = cntrl;
    robotID = id;
  }

  public byte[] getLock() { return lock;}                                                              
  public void run()
  {
    lock = new byte[0]; 
    synchronized(lock)                                          
    {
      byte[] data;
      while ((data = controller.getData()) == null)
      {
        try {
          lock.wait();  
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " + robotID + " Working" );
    }
  }

}

class RobotController
{
      private byte[] robotData;
      private Vector threadList = new Vector();                      
      private Service thread_A;
      private Service thread_B;
      private Service thread_C;
      private Service thread_D;

    public void setup(){
        thread_A = new Service(this, "A");
        thread_B = new Service(this, "B");
        thread_C = new Service(this, "C");
        thread_D = new Service(this, "D");
        threadList.addElement(thread_A);                               
        threadList.addElement(thread_B);                                
        threadList.addElement(thread_C);                                
        threadList.addElement(thread_D);                                
        thread_A.start();
        thread_B.start();
        thread_C.start();
        thread_D.start();
        start();
        stop();
      }

      public void start()
      { 
          System.out.println("START:");
          {
                for (int i=0; i <threadList.size(); i++)                                    
                {
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                  }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                      System.out.println(ie);
                  }
                  putData(new byte[10]);
                  Service rbot = (Service)threadList.elementAt(i);
                  byte[] robotLock = rbot.getLock();
                  synchronized(robotLock) {                                     
                    robotLock.notify();                                      
                  }
                }
          }
      }

      public void stop()
      {
          Collections.reverse(threadList);
          System.out.println("STOP:");
          for ( Object o : threadList) {
            System.out.println("Thread "+ o +" Stop");
          }
      }

      public synchronized byte[] getData()                          
      {
        if (robotData != null)
        {
          byte[] d = new byte[robotData.length];
          System.arraycopy(robotData, 0, d, 0, robotData.length);
          robotData = null;
          return d;
        }
        return null;
      }

      public void putData(byte[] d) { robotData = d;}

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        RobotController controller = new RobotController();
        controller.setup();
      }
}
```

Comment: this is my output:
START:
Thread A Working
Thread B Working
Thread C Working
Thread D Working
STOP:
Thread Thread[Thread-3,5,] Stop
Thread Thread[Thread-2,5,] Stop
Thread Thread[Thread-1,5,] Stop
Thread Thread[Thread-0,5,] Stop

Comment: You are not supposed to call stop() on a Thread anymore.  I believe that method has been deprecated.  The preferred method for stopping a Thread is to set something on it to cause it to stop itself.

Comment: tnx so much for your response @CodeChimp. Do you have any ides how can I start threads in this order: A-B-C-D and then stop them in reverse? My task is to do that. I need to have start() and stop() and threads should only work in sequence (print the message that they are working).

Comment: If the threads knew of each other, they could do a wait on the one it needs to wait to stop before stopping itself.

Comment: @CodeChimp do you have some good example of this?

Comment: Sorry, meant Thread.join(), not Thread.wait().  Anyhow, no, I don't.  But, if it were me, I would consider putting all my threads in a ThreadGroup, then I could do something like <thread>.getThreadGroup().enumerate(), which will populate an array with all the currently running Threads.  If you came up with a naming scheme for each thread that indicated when one's you have to wait for, you would then use that list and call join() on those threads.  All of these methods are described in the JavaDoc for Thread and ThreadGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread has name and getter `getName()`, so if you have instance of thread you can always call `thread.getName()`.

I do not know how do you access the thread name "in start" because I do not see where do you call `getName()`. However I think I know what's your problem in stop.

You store your threads in `Vector`. Then you iterate over vector's elements and print thread, so it invokes thread's `toString()`. You probably have to cast `Object` to `Thread` and call its `getName()`:

```
      System.out.println("STOP:");
      for ( Object o : threadList) {
        System.out.println("Thread "+ ((Thread)o).getName() +" Stop");
      }
```

But once you are done, I'd recommend you to find a good and new enough tutorial on java.

1. You are using not commonly applicable coding formatting.
2. You are using `Vector` instead of `List` and its implementations.
3. You are trying to use unclear technique for thread synchronization and management.

Start learning step-by-step. And do not hesitate to ask questions. Good luck.

Comment: He's accesing the name in the `run` method of `Service`. `System.out.println("Thread " + robotID + " Working" );`